# Avoiding empty table rows with initial usage of Sequelize js.

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, sequelize.js

My initialize function keep re-creating tables and inserting empty row at every time I start my server. How do I avoid this persistency? I want my table created once and ensure that I can connected to the DB and
that our Employee and Department models are represented in the database as tables using the initialize function.

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

var sequelize = new Sequelize("***database**", "**user**", "**password**", {
    host: "ec2-54-227-240-7.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
    dialect: "postgres",
    port: 5432,
    dialectOptions: {
        ssl: true
    }
});

var Employee = sequelize.define('Employee', {
    employeeNum: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
    lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
    email: Sequelize.STRING,
    SSN: Sequelize.STRING,
    addressStreet: Sequelize.STRING,
    addressCity: Sequelize.STRING,
    addressState: Sequelize.STRING,
    addressPostal: Sequelize.STRING,
    maritalStatus: Sequelize.STRING,
    isManager: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
    employeeManagerNum: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    status: Sequelize.STRING,
    department: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    hireDate: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    createdAt: false, // disable createdAt
    updatedAt: false // disable updatedAt
});

var Department = sequelize.define('Department', {
    departmentId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    departmentName: Sequelize.STRING
}, {
    createdAt: false, // disable createdAt
    updatedAt: false // disable updatedAt
});

function initialize() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sequelize.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
            Employee.create().then(function(employee) {
                resolve();
            }).catch(() => {
                reject("Unabale to sync the database");
            });

            Department.create().then(function(department) {
                resolve();
            }).catch(() => {
                reject("Unabale to sync the database");
            });
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just Change**

```
sequelize.sync({ force: true }) //<--- This will force to drop table and recreate it
```

**To**

```
sequelize.sync({ force: false , alter : true })
// this will create table if not exists but not drop by force
// and alter will update the table
```